# Reply Url from AzureAD - how to retrieve SAMLResponse

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, sustainsys-saml2

I have a Single Sign-In workflow based on Azure AD.
My project is build in .NET Core 6 + Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.

I'm able to authenticate via Azure AD, that is:
pass my Email in MS Sign in --> organisation Sign In Page ->  Verify your Identity(text or call from Microsoft) -> redirect to Reply URL on localhost.

I Have a problem with getting SAMLReponse from POST to ReplyURL.

In Network tab I see POST method to https://localhost:5002/Saml2/Acs
Status of this is 303(this seems to be odd)

```
           {
               options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("*");
               options.SPOptions.AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior = Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SigningBehavior.Never;
               options.SPOptions.MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

               options.IdentityProviders.Add(
                 new IdentityProvider(
                   new EntityId("https://sts.windows.net/*"), options.SPOptions)
                 {
                     MetadataLocation = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/*/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=*",
                 });
           });
```

When I call POST to 'callback' from Postman I get:

`Sustainsys.Saml2.Exceptions.NoSamlResponseFoundException: No Saml2 Response found in the http request.`

I think I'm missing something, not sure what

From my perspective it's look like Azure AD do POST to RepluURL, but localhost do not 'catch it', can't debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 things missing.

1. Need to load the metadata
2. ReturnURL not set in SPOptions

```cs
           {
               options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("*");
               options.SPOptions.AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior = Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SigningBehavior.Never;
               options.SPOptions.MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";
               
               //specify a location to navigate to after succesful authentication
               options.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:5002");
                    
               options.IdentityProviders.Add(
                 new IdentityProvider(
                   new EntityId("https://sts.windows.net/*"), options.SPOptions)
                 {
                     MetadataLocation = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/*/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=*",
                     //Load metadata
                     LoadMetadata = true
                 });
           });
```

Comment: I have been missing this line of code:
options.Notifications.AcsCommandResultCreated = AcsCommandResultCreated;


and method:


private void AcsCommandResultCreated(CommandResult commandResult, Saml2Response saml2Response)




At the  moment I'm able to get response from IdS, but I'm not sure how to validate SAMLResponse and what to do next.